# How to turn off line highlighting or edit its colour in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, editor, xcode8

Xcode 8 has the cursor's line automatically highlighted.

I'd like to turn this feature off.

Anyone know how? Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Xcode preferences > Fonts & Colors

Your chosen theme will have a ["current line" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQjpc.png) just under the font...

I set opacity to 0 and colour to white/furthest left.

:)

Comment: I so much wish Apple would put more resources into fixing actual bugs instead of tweaking cosmetics.

Comment: I used this answer to enable line highlighting for a custom theme, thank you :)